# Unbind to multiple namespaced events in jquery

Tags: jquery

is it possible to unbind using jquery to multiple namespaced custom events at once ?

Ex : Custom Events -

```
resize.table-100
resize.table-101
resize.table-300
```

I tried -

```
$(window).unbind("resize.")
```

It gives stack limit exceeded error however

**EDIT:**

Below seems to work but is there more strict event naming possible so that it only affects those resize events which have names as above containing table ?

```
$(window).off("resize")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove only the resize events with specified namespaces  you can do:

```
$(window).off("resize.table-100 resize.table-101 resize.table-300");
```

> [.off( events [, selector ] [, handler ] )](http://api.jquery.com/off/):
>
> events
>   Type: String
>   One or more space-separated event types and optional namespaces, or just namespaces, such as "click", "keydown.myPlugin", or ".myPlugin".

***UPDATE***

In the snippet I extended jQuery with a function so that you may write something like:

```
$(window).OffRegexNameSpaces("resize", /^table-\d{3}/);
```

In order to remove from the window element all resize events having a namespace starting with "table-" and ending with 3 digit.
This in order to avoid to write:

```
$(window).off("resize.table-100 resize.table-101 resize.table-300");
```

Snippet:

```js
//
// OffRegexNameSpaces:
// parameters: event --> single event
// regexNamespace --> a regex pattern for namespaces
//
$.fn.OffRegexNameSpaces = function (event, regexNamespace) {
  if (typeof event !== 'string' && namespaces instanceof RegExp) {
    return this;
  }
  return this.each(function (index, element) {
    var elemData = $._data(this);
    var resultNamespaces = $.map(elemData.events[event], function (eventObj, index) {
      if (regexNamespace.test(eventObj.namespace)) {
        return event + '.' + eventObj.namespace;
      }
    }.bind(element));
    if (resultNamespaces.length > 0) {
      $(this).off(resultNamespaces.join(' '));
    }
  });
};


$(window).on('resize resize.table-100 resize.table-101 resize.table-300', function(e) {
  alert(e.type + ((e.namespace === undefined || e.namespace.length == 0) ? '' : '.' + e.namespace));
});

$(function () {
  $('#btn1').on('click', function(e) {
    $(window).trigger('resize.table-100');
  })
  $('#btn2').on('click', function(e) {
    $(window).trigger('resize.table-101');
  })
  $('#btn3').on('click', function(e) {
    $(window).trigger('resize.table-300');
  })
  $('#btn4').on('click', function(e) {
    $(window).trigger('resize');
  })

  $('#btnUnbind').on('click', function(e) {
    $(window).off("resize.table-100 resize.table-101 resize.table-300");
  })

  $('#btnUnbindAll').on('click', function(e) {
    $(window).OffRegexNameSpaces("resize", /^table-\d{3}/);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<button id="btnUnbind">UnBind all resize events with namespaces</button>
<button id="btnUnbindAll">UnBind all resize events</button>
<button id="btn1">Trigger resize.table-100</button>
<button id="btn2">Trigger resize.table-101</button>
<button id="btn3">Trigger resize.table-300</button>
<button id="btn4">Trigger resize</button>
```

Comment: I have one doubt here as in my case resize.table-xxx, here xxx is variable and is being generated by jQuery plugin. So i am only aware about it starts with resize.table-

Comment: @fortm Answer updated. Take a look and let me know. Thanks.